# Генерация переменных из элементов списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у меня есть два массива:

```
p = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы p[i] стало переменной, а l[i] её значением. То есть A1 = 1, A2 = 2, A3 =3
И вызвать, например:

```
print('A1 = ', A1)
#И в консоль выдаст:
A1 = 1
```

Есть такая возможность?

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in range(3):
   globals()[p[i]]=l[i]
```

Comment: Лучше бы перебирать просто `zip(p, l)`, чтобы не привязываться к длине списков )

Comment: Может. Но не хотелось вводить новые сущности в столь коротком ответе.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: Галочку тут принято, а не спасибо)